# Jest error Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jestjs

I can't seem to find a way to fix this error from happening when I run my jest test file. 
I'm using his plugin for postMessage jquery.postmessage.js
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined

I tried importing jquery.postmessage.js into my test file but I still get this error.

Here is how I have it setup in my code.

**pagination.js**

```
$.postMessage({ method:'blaa', message:'hello', parent );
```

Then in my test file when I import pagination.js and run my test I get the error.

Anyone know how to fix this ? 
I'm not using React here I'm using jquery and webpack to bundle my modules together and jest to handle my testing.

Comment: typo `$.postMessage({ method:'blaa', message:'hello, parent );` -> `$.postMessage({ method:'blaa', message:'hello, parent'} );`

Comment: sorry that was me copying in into my ticket. I fixed that. No its not anything wrong with the postMessage call. Its to do with the unit test seeing it as undefined.